# Dynamically assigned Styles are rendered but not displayed

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView where I want to assign the background color of the row during the RowDataBound event based on the value of a cell. I do:

```
    protected void Gridview_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "0")
            {
                e.Row.Style.Add("BackColor", "yellow");
            }
            TextBox txbx = e.Row.FindControl("Txt_Criteria") as TextBox;
            txbx.Style.Add("BackColor", "yellow");
        }
    }
```

None of the 2 expressions does work... at least, everything stays white, although the code is built, as I can see in the source file.

```
<tr style="font-size:11px;BackColor:yellow;">
<input name="GridView_$ctl14$Txt_Criteria" type="text" id="GridView_Txt_Criteria_12" style="BackColor:yellow;" />
```

In order to check any interference with other style definitions, I eliminate all style references but the result stays the same.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Criteria" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="Gridview_OnRowDataBound">
    <RowStyle Font-Size="11px" />
            <Columns>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `BackColor:yellow;` is not CSS. Try `background-color:yellow;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you at least get a prize, since your code is correct, but your css is a bit wrong.

Try this:

```
e.Row.Style.Add("background-color","lightsteelblue");
```

Or in your case:

```
e.Row.Style.Add("background-color", "yellow");
```